# Is Excel clearing our http request authorization header attribute?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, excel-addins

We are trying to get our Office Excel add-in to contact one of our own Web API services so it can send and receive data from it. For the request to be authorised we must fill out the Authorization header attribute. This is how we are doing the request, which works perfectly well in all of our normal web applications.

```
this.LoginAuth = function (authString) {    
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + authString;

    return $http({
        url: MainFactory.GetWebAPILocation() + '/API/User/AddInLoginAuth',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {},
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
}
```

However, when the request is made through the add-in the Authorization attribute has been cleared down causing our request to fail. Is this clearing of the attribute being done by Excel? And if so, is there a way in which we can stop it?

Comment: Can you try adding the headers to config Object ie.,  headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json" , "Authorization" = "Basic  +authstring" }

Comment: Unfortunately if we do this, the same thing happens; the authorization header is cleared.

Comment: The AngularJS $http service ignores the `dataType: 'json'` property setting. And the `Content-Type` header in unnecessary as that is the automatic default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a CORS issue in our Web API service.